# Как создать круглый портрет в PIL?

Tags: python, pil

Есть код, который, в принцине, работает:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageOps, ImageDraw

im = Image.open('image.png')
size = (200, 200)  # размер итогового портрета

# маска
mask = Image.new('L', size, 0)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(mask) 
draw.ellipse((0, 0) + size, fill=255)

im = im.resize(size)

output = ImageOps.fit(im, mask.size, centering=(0.5, 0.5))
output.putalpha(mask)
output.thumbnail(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
output.save('image_output.png')
```

Результат - [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно, круглое изображение получается, но пропорции искажены. Как получить круглый портрет на основе исходного изображения, но с нормальными пропорциями?

Comment: Может быть, использовать `im.crop` вместо `im.resize`?

Comment: Вся проблема в том, что crop, например (100, 100) на одном изображении даст круг, а изображении другого размера срежет только углы.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я имел в виду нечто подобное:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

# Подготавливает маску, рисуя её в <antialias> раз больше и
# затем уменьшая, чтобы получилось сглаженно.
def prepare_mask(size, antialias = 2):
    mask = Image.new('L', (size[0] * antialias, size[1] * antialias), 0)
    ImageDraw.Draw(mask).ellipse((0, 0) + mask.size, fill=255)
    return mask.resize(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)

# Обрезает и масштабирует изображение под заданный размер.
# Вообще, немногим отличается от .thumbnail, но по крайней мере
# у меня результат получается куда лучше.
def crop(im, s):
    w, h = im.size
    k = w / s[0] - h / s[1]
    if k > 0: im = im.crop(((w - h) / 2, 0, (w + h) / 2, h))
    elif k < 0: im = im.crop((0, (h - w) / 2, w, (h + w) / 2))
    return im.resize(s, Image.ANTIALIAS)

size = (200, 200)

im = Image.open('image.png')
im = crop(im, size)
im.putalpha(prepare_mask(size, 4))
im.save('image_output.png')
```

Результат ([оригинал](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9G5e.jpg), [с `.thumbnail` вместо `crop`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/esqI1.png)):

[image: Результат]

Comment: Это то же самое. Пропорции искажаются. Я так понимаю, здесь нужно надевать маску с готовой alpha-рамкой на исходное изображение таким образом, чтобы все, что за круглой рамкой маски было в альфа канале.

Comment: Где же они искажаются-то? У меня, по крайней мере, [всё чётко](http://i.imgur.com/W1CuUPp.png).

Comment: У вас все четко потому, что у вас высота и ширина изображения одинаковы. То есть, оно у вас квадратное. Возьмите для примера изображение 600х300 и посмотрите результат.

Comment: Я же специально сделал понагляднее, поглядите на image_grid.png на скриншоте. Размер — 481×261. В обрезанной версии квадраты остаются квадратами. Да и кот никак не квадратный (для сравнения, вот [ваш код](http://i.imgur.com/D3nm1gM.png), неужели не видите разницы?). Да и вообще просто гляньте на содержимое `crop()`, видно же, как сохраняются пропорции. :)

Comment: Вот результат работы вашего примера - https://habrastorage.org/files/fb5/8da/55a/fb58da55a1844fb1bf74c2bf30e2101e.png

Comment: Ох, прошу прощения, опечатался в случае с вертикальными изображениями (забыл `im =`). Поправил.